# Works in jsFiddle but not in my Site

Tags: jquery, local, jsfiddle

For some reason this jQuery code I have in my site will work on jsFiddle but not locally. The code is the same. I have just copied and pasted it. Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HquKw/5/)
- [Local](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/%25resize-notworking.html)

Comment: check if the path you used to include jquery is correct

Comment: If I include other jquery it seems to work

Comment: There is a live preview box underneath the text editor. Please take note of what your question looks like so nobody's confused by invisible links. I've edited them in for you this time.

Comment: Odd characters in the code on your site: `});â€‹});` - might want to clean those up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome's developer tools, you get an error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Taking a look at the code, you see:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#workclick').click(function() {
    $("#header").height($("#headwrapper").height());

    });
    $('#workclick').click();

    $('#aboutclick, #contactclick, #introclick').click(function() {
    $("#header").height('0');
    });â€‹ // here
});
```

Some kind of encoding error...

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is complaining about a `â€‹` in your code (line 562), which happens to be an illegal character.

Answer (score 0):

I found a weird hidden character in my Jquery. Not sure where it came from or why it wasnt showing up in my editor, but I got ride of it and it works fine. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad english

i have idea for copy the full source code

steps

1. click on the Share button

   2  copy the link of on 2 box Share full screen result

3 then go that link(copy link). it show the result

4 then right click, click the view frame source.

Now your source code show

then put on the exact link of the script src and css.

now your code work