# No errors on JSFIDDLE but errors on site and jslint

Tags: javascript, html, jslint, jsfiddle

On Jsfiddle my code has no errors, see here http://jsfiddle.net/GyWpN/, Jsfiddle has built in JsLint and it says everything is fine.

On the development site though I get errors, as well as on jslint.com

In Chrome's developer tools I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` at the last line `.attr("r", 3.5);​`

and in Jslint.com I get `Unexpected '​'.` at the same last line `.attr("r", 3.5);​`

this doesn't make any sense to me, how do I get past this hurdle?

One difference worth noting is that on jsfiddle, it allows me to import the d3.v3.min.js file I need, I also import this on my development site, but jslint.com won't allow this kind of thing so I would expect it to have different errors. But this doesn't explain why the development site is having issues since it also uses the imported file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Works in jsFiddle but not in my Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322628/works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-my-site)

Comment: @RicardoLohmann that possible duplicate had a similar issue but does not have the exact same unicode error or the solution about detecting the unicode errors. I just find the kneejerk close requests disconcerting because I did put some effort into looking at existing questions and they would not have solved this issue.

Comment: @CQM a good search term for this issue is, "Unexpected Token ILLEGAL".

Comment: It's difficult to help with such little of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very end (on the last line) you have a [`Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) which raises the error. In ANSI it looks like that (see line 44):

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it happens a lot when you copy and paste code from JSFiddle.

Comment: This explains why JSLint gives the error though. It sees the ZWSP.

Comment: thanks, how did you discover it though? nothing gave me verbose errors about this issue

Comment: @CQM This is rather common problem with JSFiddle. Simple copy-paste to any advanced editor may reveal the *"hidden"* symbols.